# Spring security 5 oauth2 login

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring mvc web application that i want protect with springs security 5  Oauth2, the application successfully redirect to google for authentication, but the problem is that it keeps redirection back to the consent page just immediately after the user selects account from that consent page.
bellow is my relevant configuration.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(oauth2ClientContextFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(oauth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .anonymous()
            .disable();
}
@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails authorizationCodeResource() {
    logger.info("authorizationCodeResource");
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    details.setId("google");
    details.setClientId(environment.getProperty("google.clientId"));
    details.setClientSecret(environment.getProperty("google.clientSecret"));
    details.setUserAuthorizationUri(environment.getProperty("google.userAuthorizationUri"));
    details.setAccessTokenUri(environment.getProperty("google.accessTokenUri"));
    details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
    details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
    details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(environment.getProperty("google.reDirectURI"));
    details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
    details.setScope(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("openid")));
    return details;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
    logger.info("oauth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter");
    OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(authorizationCodeResource(), oauth2ClientContext);

    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            environment.getProperty("google.callbackURI"));

    filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    filter.setTokenServices(googleUserInfoTokenServices());

    return filter;
}

@Bean
@Description("Google API UserInfo resource server")
public GoogleUserInfoTokenServices googleUserInfoTokenServices() {
    logger.info("googleUserInfoTokenServices");
    GoogleUserInfoTokenServices userInfoTokenServices = new GoogleUserInfoTokenServices(
            environment.getProperty("google.userInfoUri"),
            environment.getProperty("google.clientId"));
    return userInfoTokenServices;
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    logger.info("authenticationEntryPoint");

    return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(environment.getProperty("google.callbackURI"));
}
```

Someone please help me. i can provide any addition details that you may require

Comment: Why do you implement it by yourself? Spring Security 5 supports common providers like Google. Just use the common provider configuration. It is easier.

Comment: I am not very conversant with the technicalities of Oauth2 operation in spring, and i don't have the time to really look into it right now, so i converted the project to a spring boot project so that i can take advantage of he auto configuration and have the app working. Thanks for your time though, i look at the techniques later.